# how to merge front end website and admin panel in react

Tags: reactjs

*Right now i have two folder in same project.*
*so now i need to access admin panel like this 'localhost:3000/admin' in same port*

Comment: show somthing about structure, and u should use react-router for making path `localhost:3000/admin` not with folders.

Comment: Thanks @b3hr4d  , but right now front and admin is running with different port , so how i can do ?

Comment: Do you have 2 nodejs project ? follow this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/

Comment: something like that , i use different port for run this admin and front , admin setup is metronic theme , and front is different

Comment: and also i make different setup for that

Answer (score 0):

it's routing issue.

**According to port:**

- one IP can display many ports - there can be a separate service on a different port (e.g. MongoDb, FE application, BE Application)
- it's should be specified in config.file
- it also can be included in package.json scripts sections like:

  PORT=3001 npm start

---

In your case, I would consider hosting two applications (admin, client) on one instance in the cloud? (one ip, there can be several ports) - or several instances.

However, answering your question more concretely and precisely: - it is a matter of routing on the application side:

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Just add one routing to the component - which contains the admin panel.

```
import AdminPage from 'Admin/MainPage';
```

---

```
const routes = {
  admin: "/admin"
};
```

---

```
<Switch>
 <Route path={routes.admin} component={AdminPanel} />
</Switch>
```